The projection of an open ball is also an open ball
My problem is as follows:
Let $\pi_i:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be the projection onto the i-th coordinate. Prove that if $A \subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is open then its projection $\pi_i(A) \subset \mathbb{R}$ is also an open set.
Resolution: Taking $a_i = \pi_i(a) \in \pi_i(A)$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $B(a;\delta) \subset A$ (since $A$ is open), hence $\pi_i(B(a;\delta)) \subset \pi_i(A)$. If we show that $B(a_i; \delta) \subset \pi_i(B(a;\delta))$, we will have that for each arbitrary $a_i \in \pi_i(A)$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $B(a_i;\delta) \subset \pi_i(A)$, i.e., the set $\pi_i(A)$ is open, as desired (actually, I saw in the book "Curso de Análise Volume 2" by Elon Lages Lima, that $B(a_i; \delta) = \pi_i(B(a;\delta))$, but there was no proof of this).
Thus the inclusion $B(a_i; \delta) \subset \pi_i(B(a;\delta))$ is sufficient to solve my problem, but I couldn't demonstrate it.

What have you tried, other than assigning your homework to us?

$B(a,\delta)$ for which norm on $\Bbb R^n$?

How did you prove $B(a_i;\delta) \supset \pi_i(B(a;\delta))$?

The inclusion $\pi_i(B(a;\delta)) \subset B(a_i; \delta)$ can be easily proven by taking $x_i = \pi_i(x) \in \pi_i(B(a;\delta))$, thus $|x - a| < \delta$, hence $|x_i - a_i| < \delta$, thus $x_i \in B(a_i;\delta)$.

The question doesn't explicitly state which norm, so I think it applies to any norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $x\in B(a_i;\delta)$, then we want to find a $y\in B(a;\delta)$, s.t. $\pi_i(y)=x$. Let $d = x-a_i \in \mathbb R$ and note that $|x|<\delta$, as $x \in B(a_i;\delta)$. Then we set $y=a+ d\,e_i$, while $e_i$ denotes the $i$th unit vector. Then we have $$||y-a||=||d\, e_i||=d<\delta,$$
thus $y\in B(a;\delta)$. Further, we have $\pi_i(y)=a_i+d=a_i+x-a_i=x$. Hence, we conclude $B(a_i;\delta) \subset \pi_i(B(a;\delta))$.

Thank you very much! This really solved my problem.
